# What makes a capacitor polarized or non-polarized?

Tags: capacitor

As far as I know, capacitors consist of two metal plates with a dielectric between them.

- How are capacitors with polarized plates manufactured?
- What makes them have polarized plates?

Comment: The plates are not polarized but the dielectric is.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks I did not know that, so how dielectric becomes polarized so I can connect it only one way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example standard electrolytic capacitors are not polarized until during manufacturing stage the thin insulating oxide layer is formed by applying voltage for electrolysis.

Which way the voltage is applied determines how the capacitor should be used to keep the oxide layer.

Under controlled conditions, using the wrong polarity in aluminum electrolytics will actually reverse the process and form a new oxide layer. So you can actually end up with just damaged or degraded capacitor with reversed polarity. This only works when the cathode's electrical connection is made of the same metal as the anode (as is true for many aluminum electrolytics), and so does not work with tantalums.

Under uncontrolled conditions, incorrect polarity causes pressure to build up and the cap may short-circuit, open-circuit, or even explode.

Comment: I am concerned that this is the accepted answer. Using wrong polarity will not just "reverse the process and form a new oxide layer." Electrolytic capacitors are famous for literally exploding when connected backwards. For most electrolytic capacitors, reversing the polarity will reverse the entire manufacturing process and put the oxide layer on your ceiling.

Comment: @MattS while I consider your answer superior, it is possible to reverse electrolytics if the cathode foil is also e.g. aluminum. However, this can't be achieved by just reversing the bias due to high current and heating. It needs a careful forming process, similar to the initial anodization process. If the cathode foil is e.g. Cu, this doesn't quite work at all.

Comment: @MattS They don't always explode. A batch of Amiga computers were manufactured with power supply  bypass caps mounted with wrong polarity and some of them still work after tens of years. And I have read application notes from multiple electrolytic capacitor manufacturers.

Comment: @Justme There are always exceptions, but they're just that -- exceptions -- and don't warrant ignoring an important safety concern. "Just a degraded capacitor with reverse polarity" is very misleading when in reality, under most circumstances, there is a serious overcurrent and explosion risk.

Comment: @tobalt I'd hoped my footnote covered that, but I think it wasn't clear or accurate enough. I edited the footnote. I agree that it's possible to form a new oxide layer -- my biggest concern here is that this answer completely ignores the explosion risk.

Comment: @MattS I just added that as a fun fact. Obviously incorrectly used caps may explode, but it does not change anything in the first part of my answer how electrolytics are manufacured to a certain polarity by forming the oxide layer by applying certain polarity at the factory. Yes, you should not apply incorrect polarity.

Comment: I think you should edit the post. You write "Using wrong polarity *will* reverse the process and form a new oxide layer." (Emphasis mine.) This is not strictly true. Using wrong polarity *may* form a new oxide layer, but using wrong polarity *may* put flying shards of metal in your eyes.

Comment: @MattS I already did. You can suggest an edit too. But the point is why caps are polarized, not what happens when you reverse polarity or otherwise mishandle it. It can still blow up due to overvoltage, overcurrent, overtemperature, over-anything, mechanical damage due vibration, etc.

Comment: You're right -- I'd forgotten that OP's added question about explosion risk was actually in a comment under a different post. I'll make a suggested edit about the actual wording, and I appreciate the discussion.

Answer (score 10):

Your intuition is right that parallel plate capacitors are inherently non-polarized. Electrolytic capacitors, however, aren't quite the same -- instead of two parallel plates separated by a dielectric, one of the conductive surfaces is a liquid electrolyte<sup>1</sup>. The other plate is a metal foil, usually aluminum, sometimes another [valve metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valve_metals).

In its proper orientation, where the aluminum is the anode, connected to the positive terminal, the aluminum foil attracts electrons and oxidizes, building up a thin layer of insulating (and high-κ) aluminum oxide, the roughness of which also maximizes surface area. You may have heard of this process, "anodizing", in other contexts.

If your aluminum side is the cathode, though, the electrolysis works in reverse, converting the aluminum oxide into aluminum metal and creating a short between the two electrodes. Current rises significantly, the electrolyte solvent boils off, and the capacitor goes *pop*. In a demonstration I did once for an undergrad lab I measured half an amp through a 10 uF cap before it blew up like a firecracker.

Tantalum capacitors are similar. An oxide layer is grown on a porous anode (made of sintered tantalum metal); the resulting tantalum oxide has a κ of 27, about 3 times more than aluminum oxide, making them very useful when high capacitance is needed in small SMD packages. And similarly to aluminum electrolytic capacitors, when they're connected in reverse, the oxide is converted to metal and a short is formed.

Choosing a capacitor is a decision with trade-offs. There's no "best" capacitor; in general, if you need high capacitance in low volume and at low cost, you have to design around your capacitor's polarity.

---

<sup>1</sup> The electrolyte is usually backed by another piece of metal foil to ensure good electrical contact, but fundamentally, the electrolyte is the electrode. Another answer talked about growing an oxide on the other piece of foil, which is possible but rarely going to occur under normal circumstances<sup>2</sup>, and depends on the particular construction of that capacitor. Though it's certainly *possible*, under most circumstances, without something to limit the current flow, the capacitor will blow up long before a complete new oxide layer forms on the former-cathode. An electrolytic capacitor in reverse polarity should not be trusted.

<sup>2</sup> It actually will occur under safe circumstances if you have two electrolytic capacitors "back-to-back" filtering an AC signal, see [the discussion under this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/647532/two-polarized-electrolytic-capacitors-in-series-vs-two-bipolars-in-parallel/647536#647536) for more details.

Comment: Huggingface says there is only 0.05% probability that an Ai wrote this :-) ie - one didn't

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks, I guess?

Answer (score 3):

In an aluminum electrolytic capacitor there are two dielectric layers separated by a conductive liquid (the electrolyte) soaked into a spacer such as paper. You can think of this as two parallel-plate capacitors in series with the electrolyte forming the connection between them.

The dielectric layer is a very thin layer of aluminum oxide that is on each plate. In addition, the plates are deliberately roughened by etching so they have much more effective surface area than the dimensions would suggest.

If both oxide layers are made the same thickness then the capacitor will withstand the same voltage in either direction and you have a non-polar electrolytic capacitor. Such a capacitor will have about half the capacitance of a similar volume polarized electrolytic. If one of the layers is made extremely thin (like the natural oxide coating aluminum gets) it will withstand a reverse voltage of a volt or two, but not more, and you'll get maximum capacitance per unit volume from the finished capacitor. Most aluminum electrolytic capacitors are made like this.

The thick oxide layer is grown in an electrochemical anodizing bath with a platinum electrode and the aluminum foil, in the processes I've seen in operation.

Recall that the total capacitance of two capacitors in series is

Ct = \$\frac{C_1 \cdot C_2}{C_1 + C_2}\$

So the capacitance will be dominated by the smaller capacitance if the two are much different.

Comment: Huggingface says you write SLIGHTLY more like an Ai than most :-). But only slightly. I've tried to do so with not much success

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks (?) 8-)

Answer (score 1):

Capacitors with polarized plates are made by using materials with different electrical properties for the positive and negative plates. The positive plate is typically made of a material with a high electron affinity, such as aluminum, while the negative plate is made of a material with a low electron affinity, such as tantalum. The dielectric material, which is a non-conductive substance that separates the two plates, is typically an insulator such as ceramic or paper.

When a voltage is applied to the capacitor, the positive plate attracts electrons from the negative plate, creating an excess of electrons on the negative plate and a deficiency of electrons on the positive plate. This creates an electric field within the capacitor that stores energy. The direction of the electric field is from the positive plate to the negative plate, which is why the plates are said to be polarized.

To manufacture a capacitor with polarized plates, the positive and negative plates are typically made from thin sheets of the appropriate material and then coated with a thin layer of the dielectric material. The plates are then rolled or stacked together and encased in a protective housing to form the finished capacitor.

**EDIT:**

It's true that both electrodes in a capacitor are made of metal and have some electron affinity, but the way that a capacitor stores and releases electrical charge is fundamentally different from the way that a battery or other energy source works. A capacitor stores electrical energy in the form of an electrostatic field between its two electrodes, rather than by chemical reactions like a battery.

When a capacitor is connected backwards, or "reverse-biased," it can cause problems in a circuit. If a voltage is applied to the capacitor in the wrong direction, the voltage across the capacitor may exceed the rating of the dielectric material, causing it to break down and become conductive. This can result in a large amount of current flowing through the capacitor, which can lead to overheating and potentially cause the capacitor to explode.

It's important to always connect a capacitor in the correct direction, following the markings on the capacitor or the schematic diagram of the circuit. This ensures that the capacitor is used within its rated voltage and current limits, which helps to prevent damage to the component and the circuit as a whole.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, one more question: why it explodes if I connect it backwards? Aren't both poles are metal plates with more ore less electron affinity?

Comment: @VintonCerf see my edit.

Comment: This answer appear to be largely AI generated. Is it? || The first paragraph is vaguely general and essentially incorrect. The aluminum / tantalum description appears close to untrue. It certainly does not apply to the vast quanities of aluminium electrolytic capacitors or tantalum capacitors. As a general description it is dangerously misleading. This is the sort of answer that an Ai might be expected to give - and is the reason that their use needs to be carefully managed.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yes very likely. Also it does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Huggingface: 1st two paragraphs - 98.2% likely AI made. || Edit 99.85% 1st 2 paragraphs Ai probability. || FWIW